# error of bash string concatenation

Tags: bash

For me bash script is always some kind of tricky. I have

```
web_dir=/tng4/users/ldiao/AQF/wrf-chem-result/
rm "$web_dir""three_days_ago/*.gif"
```

the error message is

```
rm: cannot remove '/tng4/users/ldiao/AQF/wrf-chem-result/three_days_ago/*.gif': 
No such file or directory
```

But if I change to

```
rm "$web_dir"three_days_ago/*.gif""
```

then it works. There is no spell errors. Can someone explains for me the reason? thanks!

Comment: The globbing characters `*`, `?` etc are not expanded within quotes, but they are interpreted literally. To find out why they designed it like this, you would probably have to ask one of the language's developers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that [bash globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) does not work inside `" "`

Correct variant would be

```
rm -- "$web_dir/three_days_ago/"*.gif
```

Also, use `-i` option when playing with rm. This way if you make a mistake or a typo it wont delete all of your files unless you confirm that.

Comment: And just to be precise, your second example works because you have `$web_dir` properly in double quotes, followed by unquoted `three_days_ago/*.gif`, followed by a completely superfluous double-quoted empty string. For what it's worth, the idiomatic way to quote that would be something like `"${web_dir}three_days_ago"/*.gif`

Comment: @tripleee I always suggest to use extra ``/`` between variables. Just in case you forget to end your variable with a slash. Two slashes wont hurt. So I'd edit your example to ``"${web_dir}/three_days_ago"/*.gif``. Also it seems like there's no difference if you put a slash after the quote or right before it.

Comment: Right, the slash is not a metacharacter to the shell, so it doesn't require quoting; but on the other hand, quoting regular characters is harmless.